# Styled components for nested html elements (React)

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am new to styled-components, and want to know how you would write it given the following html snippet:

```
  <div class="segmentedControlContainer">
    <input type="radio" name="segmentedControlExample" value="1" id="1" />
    <label for="1"> One </label>

    <input type="radio" name="segmentedControlExample" value="2" id="2" />
    <label for="2"> Two </label>

    <input type="radio" name="segmentedControlExample" value="3" id="3" />
    <label for="3"> Three </label>
   <div>
```

so far, I have defined

```
export const SegmentedControlWrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    user-select: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: solid 1px #bcbcbc
`

export const Input = styled.input`
    display: none;
    &:checked + label {
        color: #fff;
        background: #blah;
    }
`

export const Label = styled.label`
    flex: 1;
    color: #blah;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    cursor: pointer;

   &:checked {


    }

    &:not(:last-child){
     ....
    }
`
```

and use it in react as:

```
<SegmentedControlWrapper>
  <Input />
  <Label />
</SegmentedControlWrapper>
```

Most of this is correct, and I think the checked state isn't styled propelry. Any pointer would be appreciated. As I am confused with using &, >, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Pass checked or not checked as props to style class. It will help to style in good way.

```
export const Input = styled.input

display: none;
&:checked + label {
    color: #fff;
    background: {$props => {this.props.checked ? "some" : "some"}}
}
<Input checked={this.state.checked}/>
```

Comment: Hi UI Dev, I thought html for radio button already have checked state, hence I didn't use react state. e.g. ```<input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey"
         checked>```

Comment: Hi, UI Dev. I got it working. i just used the wrong html tag. I used 'for' on label instead of 'htmlFor'. So now, when you click on each radio, it is checked.